# Why does Map not extend Collection interface

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

Why doesn't `java.util.Map` interface extend the `java.util.Collection` interface?  Isn't a `java.util.Map` a collection of Key-Value pairs?

Comment: it is not. the Map.entrySet() is, if implemented.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Collection assume elements of one value.  Map assumes entries of key/value pairs.  They could have been engineered to re-use the same common interface however some methods they implement are incompatible e.g.

```
Collection.remove(Object) - removes an element.
Map.remove(Object) - removes by key, not by entry.
```

You could model a Map as a collection of entries, which is what `Map.entrySet()` does.

There are some methods in common; `size()`, `isEmpty()`, `clear()`, `putAll/addAll()` but these are unlikely to have much value as a stand alone interface. (Again `Map.entrySet()` can be used instead)

Answer (score 21):

Because the `Collection` interface is largely incompatible with the `Map` interface. If `Map` extended `Collection`, what would the `add(Object)` method do?

The two interfaces have very different semantics. If you need the values or the keys of a `Map` as collections, you can always use `keySet()`/`values()`.

Answer (score 4):

Because some methods declared in `Collections` do not fit a `Map` interface and vice versa.

An example for the first is the `add(Object)` method of the `Collections` interface, 
an example of the second is the `put(K, V)` of the `Map` interface. 
There is simply no consistent way to sensibly implement `add(Object)` for a Map - is it a key, is it a value? The same is valid for `put(K, V)`. What could possibly be a key in an `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 3):

> Why doesn't java.util.Map interface
>   extend the java.util.Collection interface?

`Map` is a key/value pair whereas `Collection` is a collection of a group of objects stored in a structured manner and has a specified access mechanism. The reason why Map doesn't extend Collections interface is that `add(E e);` doesn't cater the key value pair like Map's `put(K, V)`.

Also, what would Collection's `iterator()` method point to if `Map` had to extend it? The key's iterator or value's iterator?

Answer (score 1):

All collections must implement a default constructor and another constructor that takes a collection as a parameter. You can't construct a map with any other collection other than a map.

Since Map imposes restrictions on the type of objects it can hold, you can't implement a map as a collection.

Comment: The two constructors are **not** a strict requirement: they apply only to *general-purpose* collections (i.e. not to specialized ones) and it's written as '*should* provide two "standard" constructors', so even for general-purpose collections it's not an absolute must.