# Why can't we use Iterator on a Map(Java)?

Tags: java

I understand that to iterate through a `Map`, I need to use the `entrySet()` method and then use the `Iterator` on the resultant `Set`. I feel the question might be silly, but, how is the `Map` exactly implemented so that using an `Iterator` on it directly isn't possible? As far as I understand, `Map` isn't a collection, and `Iterator` is meant to be used over a collection. But logically, isn't `Map` also a collection of key-value pair(though it doesn't implement the `Collection` interface)?

Comment: I guess I found the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700135/why-does-map-not-extend-collection-interface.

Comment: Not sure that answers your question really. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AFAIK, You can't iterate over a Map directly because there are three types of iteration that a Map supports and there was no clear reason to choose one of the other.  Doing the equivalent `entrySet().iterator()` may have been reasonable, but it's not the choice which was made.

Answer (score 7):

Do you want to iterate the entries (key+value) or only keys or only values? That's why you obtain the specific collection and obtain an iterator.

Since keys/entries are unique (no duplicate elements present), you obtain a set through `entrySet()` and `keySet()`. And since values can have duplicates, you obtain the collection through `values()` and then get an iterator from these.

Comment: What would be the problem of implementing iteration over maps the way it is done in C++ STL: an iterator points to a std::pair<key, value>, and you pick either  `first` or `second` based on what you need?

Answer (score 4):

Collection implements Iterator, and Map though **doesnt fall into** `java.util.Collection`, its still considered in the Collection framework.

This is what i use to iterate a Map

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what value the programmer is seeking to iterate. Either it's just keys or values or both. based on that, we have three different objects that can be iterated. Example: `mapObject.keySet().iterator()`; or `mapObject.values().iterator()`; or `mapObject.entrySet().iterator()`. The only thing to keep in mind is that, when we iterate over just `values()` collection, we won't get respective keys by any means.