# How and why is Kotlin's `Map` iterable even though it is not `Iterable`?

Tags: loops, kotlin, iterable, standard-library

As it was in Java, any object that is `Iterable` can be used in an enhanced for loop. I thought the same held true for Kotlin as well, until I discovered that `kotlin.collections.Map` is not `Iterable` at all.

*from the standard library source code:*

```kotlin
public interface Map<K, out V> {
    // ....
```

If not, then how is something like this possible?:

```kotlin
val map: Map<String, Int> = HashMap()
// ...
for ((s, i) in map) {
    println(s)
    println(i)
    // works perfectly
}
```

Finally, is it possibly to make custom classes that support this syntax? If so, how?

Comment: `has a member or an extension function iterator() that returns Iterator<>`: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#for-loops

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/iterator.html

Comment: And the code: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/6a670dc5f38fc73eb01d754d8f7c158ae0176ceb/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Maps.kt#L373

Comment: `Map.entries()` is Iterable. Same as in Java, Map is not itself iterable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Kotlin for loop is [*defined by convention*](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/operator-overloading.html#operator-overloading):

> Some syntax forms in Kotlin are *defined by convention*, meaning that their semantics are defined through syntactic expansion of one syntax form into another syntax form.

In the case of `for(VarDecl in C) Body`, the syntax form that it expands to is:

```
when(val $iterator = C.iterator()) {
    else -> while ($iterator.hasNext()) {
                val VarDecl = $iterator.next()
                <... all the statements from Body>
            }
```

as specified [here in the spec](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/statements.html#for-loop-statements).

Rather than requiring a particular interface, it is only required that overload resolution finds appropriate `operator` overloads for `iterator()`, `hasNext()` and `next()`. As an extreme example, this compiles!

```
fun main() {
    for (s in Foo()) { // no error here!
        
    }
}

class Foo {
    operator fun iterator(): Bar = Bar()
}

class Bar {
    operator fun hasNext() = false
    operator fun next() = ""
}
```

In your case, there [exists](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/iterator.html) an extension function `iterator` for `Map`:

```
operator fun <K, V> Map<out K, V>.iterator(): Iterator<Entry<K, V>>
```

and `MutableMap`:

```
@JvmName("mutableIterator") 
operator fun <K, V> MutableMap<K, V>.iterator(): MutableIterator<MutableEntry<K, V>>
```

The `iterator` method don't have to be declared in `Map` - as long as overload resolution can resolve it, the for loop works. The same applies to `next` and `hasNext`.

So to make your own class work with for loops, the minimum you need is to declare:

```
operator fun iterator(): Iterator<Something>
```

But I would still suggest that you implement `Iterable`, because then you get all the `Iterable` extension functions for free :)

Comment: I understand that extension functions are awesome and they allow Map to act like it's Iterable, but since those extension functions are a part of the standard library anyway, why not just make Map Iterable? and have those extension functions as member functions.

Comment: @SMMH I cannot give you a definitive answer for why `Map` is not *designed* to implement `Iterable` because I did not design it, but if I had to guess, it is because a map can be viewed from many perspectives - you can see it as a collection of keys, a collection values, or a collection of entries. It can't implement all of those interfaces at once because of type erasure, so this is what we've got. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422365/reason-hashmap-does-not-implement-iterable-interface

Comment: It can't be `Iterable` because on JVM it's mapped to `java.util.Map` which doesn't extend `java.lang.Iterable`. I don't know if that's the only reason, but it's a sufficient one.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov but then that just raises the question of “why doesn’t JVM’s `Map` implement `Iterable`”, which is why I gave a link with possible answers to *that* instead.

Comment: But you should be clear it's a different question.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov You’re right. I admit that I could have made it clearer.