# Java collection not have Map as part of collection framework

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

If your look at [**collection framework**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) you will see the following, but Map is not in the list of interfaces. While we talk about map we say it is a part of collection framework, so if Map is a part of collection framework then why it is not in the interfaces list.

```
 java.util
Interface Collection

All Known Subinterfaces:
    BeanContext, BeanContextServices, List, Set, SortedSet

All Known Implementing Classes:
    AbstractCollection, AbstractList, AbstractSet, ArrayList, BeanContextServicesSupport, BeanContextSupport, HashSet, LinkedHashSet, LinkedList, TreeSet, Vector
```

Comment: Similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700135/why-does-map-not-extend-collection-interface

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Maps` work with `key/value pairs`, while the `other collections` work with `just values`. Map maps keys to values. It allows its content to be viewed as a set of keys, a collection of values and a set of key-value mappings.

Check this following link. Answer by oracle.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/

Answer (score 18):

"The collection framework" and `Collection` interface are not the same thing.

While you *can* regard a map as a collection of entries, `Map` doesn't support that directly - you can get a set of entries with the `entrySet` method.

But fundamentally you need to distinguish between "the collection framework" and the `Collection` interface.

Answer (score 4):

Because Map is three collections: Keys, values and key-value pairs.

It's not easy to decide which one should be the default to iterate over, so it implements the interface three times (`keySet()`, `values()` and `entrySet()`)

Answer (score 4):

It's part of the collection framework but it doesn't implement the `java.util.Collection` interface.

It's a different branch of the hierarchy. If you want, you can view it on the same level of the hierarchy as the Collection interface.

The Collection interface is implemented by (is the root of) List-like Collections while Map is implemented by(is the root of) the KEY-VALUE-like collections.

Answer (score 1):

The `Map` interface is not an extension of the `Collection` interface. However, it is a structure for keeping collections of data.